# How to get extract even keys from Map?

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, function, dart

I would like to extract the even keys from my Map and put them in another sheet/array for further work with them. I wrote a function, but it returns me all the keys of my Map tell me how I can fix it?

```
void main() {
final  evenNum = [];
final testMap = <int, String>{
    1: 'Text',
    2: 'Text',
    3: 'Text',
    4: 'Text',
    5: 'Text',
    6: 'Text',
  };

 for (var n in testMap.keys){
    if(n / 2 == 0);
     evenNum.add(n);
}
 print(evenNum);
}
```

Comment: `print(testMap.keys.where((i) => i.isEven));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue on end colon`if(n / 2 == 0);` and `%`(modular) instead of `/`(division)

It will be

```dart
if (n % 2 == 0) {
  evenNum.add(n);
}
```

Or you can use

```dart
if (n.isEven) {
  evenNum.add(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the condition in the if statement, you should use mod operator  like this:

```
if (n % 2 == 0){
  evenNum.add(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
void main() {
  final evenNum = [];
  final testMap = <int, String>{
    1: 'Text',
    2: 'Text',
    3: 'Text',
    4: 'Text',
    5: 'Text',
    6: 'Text',
  };

  for (var n in testMap.keys) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      evenNum.add(n);
    }
  }

  print(evenNum);
}
```

Result: `[2, 4, 6]`

Answer (score 1):

As user **pskink** suggested in his comment, you should use [`.where`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) for the most concise way to get all the even keys. A for loop would also work as others have suggested.

```dart
void main() {
  final testMap = <int, String>{
    1: 'Text',
    2: 'Text',
    3: 'Text',
    4: 'Text',
    5: 'Text',
    6: 'Text',
  };

  final evenNums = testMap.keys.where((key) => key.isEven);

  // assert that every number is even -> true
  assert(evenNums.every((number) => number.isEven));
}
```